# Long table: update caption after a manual pagebreak

Tags: tables, captions, longtable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}      
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{Table 1: my first elaborate caption}\\
\end
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\
\hline
\endhead
A & A & A\\
A & A & A\\
\ldots
A & A & A\\

% 1st manual pagebreak: rows before this pagebreak share a common
%                       property A and now they share property B
\pagebreak
% THIS DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED:  
\caption{Table 1 continued: following rows share property b (caption updated)}\\
B & B & B\\
B & B & B\\
\ldots
B & B & B\\

% 2nd manual pagebreak: now rows have property C which again should be mentioned in the caption 
\pagebreak
% THIS DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED:
\caption{Table 1 continued: following rows share property c}\\
C & C & C\\
C & C & C\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

How can I update the caption for later pages within the longtable environment?

I am printing a list of subgroups and insert pagebreaks manually after selected subgroup indices. For example, the first two pages list all subgroups with index 2 to 4. The third and fourth page lists subgroups with index 6 and 8. The fifth page subgroups with index 9. And the remaining pages subgroups with index 12.

Of course, I could define several longtables, but they share the same header row. This means I would have to copy and maintain manually the shared header row.

Comment: What are property A, B, ... ? Where are defined? Your question is unclear.

Comment: They are subgroup indices. They are content related not LaTeX related.

Comment: are this mean, that in each caption is some explanation of following table body? Why you not simple write this in `multicolum` cells, which you insert them  after each `\pgebreak`?

Answer (score 2):

#### Insert manually pagebreaks, captions & header rows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

% Define shared header row in a re-usable command:
\newcommand{\myheader}{%
\hline
Subgroup index & Column 2 & Column 3\\
\hline}

\begin{document}      
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
% Page 1
\caption{My first elaborate caption\label{longtable} what subgroups the long table shows beginning with index 2}\\
\myheader
\endfirsthead
2 & A & A\\
2 & A & A\\
\vdots\\
4 & A & A\\
\hline

\pagebreak\\
% Page 2
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{\textbf{Table \ref{longtable} Continued:} subgroups with index 6 and 8}}\\
\myheader
6 & B & B\\
6 & B & B\\
\vdots\\
8 & B & B\\
\hline

\pagebreak\\
% Page 3
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{\textbf{Table \ref{longtable} Continued:} subgroups with index 9}}\\
\myheader
9 & C & C\\
\vdots\\
9 & C & C\\
\hline

\pagebreak\\
% Page 4
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{\textbf{Table \ref{longtable} Continued:} subgroups with index 12}}\\ % still index 9
\myheader
9 & C & C\\
\vdots\\
9 & C & C\\
\hline

% ...
\pagebreak\\
% Page 9
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\parbox{\LTcapwidth}{\textbf{Table \ref{longtable} Continued:} subgroups with index 12}}\\ % still index 12
\myheader
9 & C & C\\
\vdots\\
9 & C & C\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I assume that the package `longtable` stores the header row with the `\endfirsthead` command somewhere. If someone knows how I could refer to this avoiding to have a `\newcommand{}`, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\endfirsthead` and `\endhead` also for the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}      
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
\caption{my first elaborate caption}\\\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\\hline
\endfirsthead

\caption{continued: following rows share property c}\\
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3\\\hline
\endhead

A & A & A\\
A & A & A\\
\ldots
A & A & A\\

% 1st manual pagebreak: rows before this pagebreak share a common
%                       property A and now they share property B
\pagebreak
B & B & B\\
B & B & B\\
\ldots
B & B & B\\

\pagebreak
C & C & C\\
C & C & C\\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this works only if I need two different captions and the first one is only for the first page. But I need the general case N captions each with several pages .

Comment: then use a `\multicolumn` after the manual page break

Comment: Yes, that would be a possibility. It means I have to add all pagebreaks and captions manually. In my case this is actually feasible: I have a 9-pages table with five different captions. The subsequent captions are quite short. Repeating them does not bother me.

Comment: I am struggling with the order of the shared header row and the modified caption: `\pagebreak\multicolumn...` prints first the shared header row and then the manually inserted caption. Well, I guess this was to be expected. If I also have to add manually the shared header row, it means I have to maintain the shared header row over 9 pages which again leads easily to inconsistencies. In this case I would keep searching for a more automated solution.

Comment: with `\multicolumn` you can use _only_  `\endfirsthead` with `\caption`

Comment: I see. Thanks for your feedback. I appreciate it.

Comment: Doesn't the `\caption{…}` after the first increase the table counter?